# How to protect from editing only rows that are odd numbered?

Tags: google-sheets, range, row, spreadsheet-protection

In Google Sheets how do I protect the rows in Column A which are odd from any kind of edits?

I would like to use this function

```
=ISODD(ROW(A1))
```

Protected sheets and ranges gives you this by default

```
Sheet1!A1
```

I can do this

```
Sheet1!A1:A1000
```

which will protect all 1000 rows but how do I use functions in that so I can only use ODD rows.

Here is a picture of that feature:

[image: ODD rows]

Comment: you know how to do this? which tag should i add javascript?

Comment: `google-apps-script` but see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721&q=range%20protection&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner (still not possible to manipulate range protection with GAS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments on your question, I don't believe there is [currently](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721&q=range%20protection&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner) any way of manipulating range protection with Google Apps Script.

So the only option that I can think of is to manually apply the protection to 500 individual cells (in your example).

A workaround - that is not particularly tidy - is to use data validation to thwart (ultimately not prevent) entering data in even rows, with this sort of arrangement (accessed from Data, Validation...):

[image: Data validation example]

Savvy users who have access to the spreadsheet will be able to go in to data validation and circumvent this, though.

Comment: Sorry, the "Show help" message doesn't really make sense, because it will appear in odd rows as well. But you might think of something more appropriate.

Comment: It's perfect better then locking imo since it doesn't gray the cells for other people. any way to protect all cells without graying (probably also using this method of data validation)

Comment: The user can uncheck Protected ranges in the View menu to not show the grey shaded area. But that might not be the usage you are looking for.

Comment: yeah I want it by default for any user ya.. ah it's good enough.

Comment: The issue 1721, pointed on the "currently" link was fixed on Feb 2015. Reference https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1721#c166. See the other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31052398/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Google has created api for [protecting sheets](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.in/2015/02/control-protected-ranges-and-sheets-in.html) using google app script.

For example, to protect range A1:B10, You can run

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = ss.getRange('A1:B10');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
```

If You want to protect rows alternatively, You can try something like this

```
function alternateRowProtection() {
  var totalRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getNumRows();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = 1;
  while (row < totalRows)
  {
      if(row%2 == 0){
           sheet.getRange(row).protect().setDescription('This is protected.');    
      }
    row++;
  }
}
```